# MatchQ-ing Associations (MMA 10)

Tags: pattern-matching, version-10, associations

Consider

```
{x->1}
```

which has `FullForm`

```
List[Rule[x, 1]]
```

and, therefore,

```
MatchQ[{x->1}, List[___Rule]]
```

produces `True`.

Now consider

```
<|x->1|>
```

which has `FullForm`

```
Association[Rule[x, 1]]
```

but

```
MatchQ[<|x->1|>, Association[___Rule]]
```

produces `False`

In fact,

```
MatchQ[<|x->1|>, Association[___]]
```

produces `False`.  Any ideas?  (I'm trying to make some MathLink xxxxxxxx WSTP functions for serializing C structs as Associations, and this lacuna is messing me up).

Comment: `MatchQ[ Normal @ <|x->1|>, Normal @ Association[ x -> _ ]` or `MatchQ[ Normal @ <|x->1|>, List[ ___ Rule] ]` will work though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) is atomic:

```
<|x -> 1|> // AtomQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Therefore standard pattern matching *inside* the structure will not work.

You can still match on the implicit head using:

```
MatchQ[<|x -> 1|>, _Association]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

There is also [`AssociationQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AssociationQ.html):

```
<|x -> 1|> // AssociationQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
MatchQ[<|x -> 1|>, _?AssociationQ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

I used the term atomic in a general way meaning an object that does not conform to the standard expression syntax and traversal rules.  Taliesin Beynon explains why this is conflating two different concepts in [this chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/conversation/taliesin-on-atomq-and-normalq).

Comment: It just so happens that Association is currently AtomQ, though I've argued strongly against that fact internally, and I've got SW's say-so that we'll change that eventually. But that doesn't have all that much to do with pattern matching not working inside associations: we all agree it should, it's just hard to do efficiently and we couldn't deliver it for 10. So, to sum up: Association will not be AtomQ forever, and it will support pattern matching eventually. There's a correlation here, not a causation.

Comment: @Taliesin Thanks for the clarification, however I'm afraid I don't understand it.  If `Assocation` objects were standard *Mathematica* expressions then pattern matching would work by default, would it not?  I realize pattern matching could be overloaded for an Atomic object as I believe it is for `Complex`, but I still think there is causation here.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: I can see that pattern-matching over the *contents* of an `Association` would be difficult.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: A possibly similar problem arises, for instance, in deciding whether the two JSON objects `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1}` are equal; the problem explodes with size, requiring either some arbitrary sort on the keys or considering $n!$ possibilities (modulo nesting).

Comment: @Reb.Cabin, since the sorting is arbitrary can't the data be normalized internally? eg like FullForm[x + 1] == FullForm[1 + x] = Plus[1,x]

Comment: @alancalvitti -- yes, it can, but, so far as I know, there is no standard for this in JSON and developers often write really bad code for testing equality of JSON objects.  Mathematica has a standard (if obscure) order for terms in expressions and freely reorders things for you in evaluation. But an Association is probably reordered in Hash order or Trie order or something else altogether and would have to be reordered for pattern matching.  That's my guess -- just a guess -- why Taliesen said it's difficult to be efficient.

Answer (score 11):

In *Mathematica* **10.4**, [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html) can now be used in pattern matching. Here is the result of the OP's example:

```
MatchQ[<|x -> 1|>, Association[___Rule]]
```

> True

and

```
MatchQ[<|x->1|>, Association[___]]
```

> True

There's now also [`KeyValuePattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KeyValuePattern.html) which is a pattern object specifically to match elements of an `Association` or list of rules. Here are some examples:

```
<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|> /. KeyValuePattern[x_ -> 1] :> x
```

> a

```
Cases[{
  <|"PartOfSpeech" -> "Noun", "Number" -> "Singular"|>,
  <|"PartOfSpeech" -> "Verb"|>},
 KeyValuePattern[{x : "PartOfSpeech" -> y : "Noun"}] :> 
  Association[x -> y]]
```

> {<|"PartOfSpeech" -> "Noun"|>}

Comment: Good to know! Just after I posted http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119542/6804