# Converting hierarchies of rules to associations

Tags: data-structures, rule, associations

The impossibility of `MatchQ`-ing inside and `Association` [MatchQ-ing Associations (MMA 10)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55526/matchq-ing-associations-mma-10) explains a problem I have. I would like to convert hierarchical lists of rules to hierarchies of Associations. As an example:

```
rdata = {"a" -> {"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}}, "d" -> 3}
```

Then

```
rdata /. List -> Association
```

returns

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> Association[7, 8, 9]|>, "d" -> 3|>
> ```

where a value that happens to be a list is converted to something meaningless, which is not wanted. I have tried a variety of things like:

```
rdata /. x : {__Rule} :> Association[x]
```

or

```
(rdata /. List -> Association) /. x_Association /; NotAssociationQ[x] :> List @@ x
```

or

```
rdata /. {x__Rule} :> Association[x]
```

but none of them solves the problem.
I finally managed it by picking out the locations of all the lists of `Rule`s, as follows:

```
rtoA = (# /. {x__Rule} -> Association[x]) &
RulesToAssociation[rdata_] := Module[{pos},
  pos = Drop[#, -1] & /@ Position[rdata, Rule];
  Association @@ MapAt[rtoA, rdata, pos]]
RulesToAssociation[rdata]
```

which returns the desired result

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}|>, "d" -> 3|>
> ```

In my real application the rules list comes from the `Import` of a fairly complicated *JSON* file. This solution seems to work but I'm not sure how robust it is.  Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 31):

There is a `ToAssociations` function in the `` GeneralUtilities` `` package that is perfect for this and for converting nested JSON rules to associations:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
ToAssociations@rdata
(* <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}|>, "d" -> 3|> *)
```

This preserves the inner most list that is not a list of rules.

---

As for your original attempts, the reason a replacement like `x : {__Rule} :> Association[x]` does not work is because `Association` is atomic and when `/.` replaces the outer most list with `Association`, you lose the ability to "inspect" inside and make replacements.

Instead, what you want is something that replaces inside out, and you can use `Replace` with the appropriate level spec:

```
Replace[rdata, x : {__Rule} :> Association[x], {0, Infinity}]
(* <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}|>, "d" -> 3|> *)
```

Comment: Nice job.  You gave the answer I was going to give *and* showed me a new function. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was trying to figure out how to get Replace to work like that but I was thinking in terms of the /. syntax and it never occurred to me that it would have level specs.      There seems to be no mention of the GeneralUtilities` package in the Help Browser, as far as I can tell ?

Comment: @JohnJowett Yes, it is undocumented at present.

Comment: `ToAssociations` do not work for lists with `RuleDelayed`, I used you second method as `Replace[rdata, 
 x : {__RuleDelayed | __Rule} :> Association[x], {0, Infinity}]`. Tks! +1

Comment: @rm-rf Please see my answer and remarks concerning the `/.` replacement mechanism ... How to explain my result ?.

Comment: This is now also available as `ResourceFunction["ToAssociations"]`

Answer (score 10):

Version 10.2 introduces direct importing of JSON data as nested Associations.

[`"RawJSON"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/RawJSON.html):

> The "RawJSON" format identifies JSON objects of the form <sub>[image]</sub> with associations of the form <sub>[image]</sub> in the Wolfram Language.

Among others the documentation gives this example:

```
Import["http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&\
titles=Wolfram%20Language&continue=&format=json", "RawJSON"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to get the desired output using `/.` with this **2-steps approach** :

```
rdata //. p : {__Rule} :> foo @@ p /. foo -> Association
(* <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}|>, "d" -> 3|> *)
```

## Explanations

### First step

Using `//.` we find **at all levels** in `rdata` the occurrences of the target structure `{__Rule}` that we need to replace in and we temporarily tag it as `foo`

```
fs = rdata //. p : {__Rule} :> foo @@ p
```

One could use a more specific rule instead, for example:

```
fs = rdata //. p : {Rule[_String, _] ..} :> foo @@ p
```

It returns a result which has already the correct final structure :

```
foo["a" -> foo["b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}], "d" -> 3]
```

If `foo` is replaced by `Association` then we'll get the desired output.

### Second step

It appears that we can use directly `/.` to replace `foo` **at all the levels** and **at the same time**:

```
fs /. foo -> Association
(*<|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}|>, "d" -> 3|>*)
```

## Discussion

This result surprised me because it is **in contradiction** with the replacement mechanism given in @rm-rf answer :

"*the reason a replacement like `x : {__Rule} :> Association[x]` does not work is because Association is **atomic** and when /. replaces **the outer most** list with Association, you lose the ability to "inspect" inside and make replacements*"

**The two reasons why the replacement in my second step should not work are : 1./ the fact that the replacement is made starting from the outermost level to the inner one and 2./ Association is Atomic**

#### 1.Difference between `/. foo -> f` and `/. foo[x_]->f[x]`

One must indeed distinguish these two cases :

```
foo["a", foo["b"], "c"] /. foo -> fff
(* fff["a", fff["b"], "c"] *)
```

and  :

```
foo["a", foo["b"], "c"] /. foo[x__] -> fff[x]
(* fff["a", foo["b"], "c"] *)
```

As well explained by @WReach in the comments :

*"Example 1 matches foo heads only. As they have no subparts to skip, the inner foo is visited and replaced. Example 2 matches foo[x__] which does have subparts that are skipped, and we can see the inner foo subpart is left unchanged."*

which is for me more clear than the documentation of "/." (`ReplaceAll`) :

[image]

Clearly, **the fact that I replace Heads only in my second step allow me to make this replacement at all levels.**

But it should not work either because ...

#### 2. `Association` is an atomic expression

which means that it is by definition "locked" in such a way that it can't be modified with tools like `/.`.
For example :

```
asoc = Association[{a -> x, b -> y, c -> z}]
(* <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|> *)
```

then

```
asoc /. x->xx
(* <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|> *)
```

shows no replacement is possible inside the `Assocation`.

This means that my second step shouldn't work also :

```
foo["a" -> foo["b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}], "d" -> 3] /. foo -> Association
(* <|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "c" -> {7, 8, 9}|>, "d" -> 3|> *)
```

If the outer most `foo` is replaced first then it should prevent the inner replacement from taking place ... which is not the case.

This probably simply means that the whole expression to be replaced is maintained in an unevaluated form until all replacements are made...

Comment: We know that matching works from the outermost level inward from the documentation statement that after a match _no further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts_.  Example 1 matches `foo` heads only.  As they have no subparts to skip, the inner `foo` is visited and replaced.  Example 2 matches `foo[x__]` which does have subparts that are skipped, and we can see the inner `foo` subpart is left unchanged.  Examples 3 and 4 give the same results as examples 1 and 2 respectively.  Sow/reap tells us nothing here since the values are all being sown before replacement occurs.

Comment: To see this all in action, constrast `foo[2, foo[1], 3] /. e:foo[x__] /; (Print[e];True) :> fff[x]` to `Replace[foo[2, foo[1], 3], e:foo[x__] /; (Print[e]; True) :> fff[x], {0, Infinity}]`

Comment: @WReach Thank you for your clear explanations. I modified my post (and also removed my shameful mistake concerning `Sow` :(()