# Using ReplaceAll to replace a head

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Why would this work to replace the head `b` with `newHead`:

```
b[c, d] /. head_[arg__] :> newHead[arg]
(* newHead[c, d] *)
```

but when `b` is nested within another head `a`, only `a` is replaced using the same rule:

```
a[b[c, d]] /. head_[arg__] :> newHead[arg]
(* newHead[b[c,d]] *)
```

Using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`), and `HoldPattern` did not help:

```
a[b[c, d]] //. head_[arg__] :> newHead[arg]
a[b[c, d]] /. HoldPattern[head_[arg__]] :> newHead[arg]
a[b[c, d]] //. HoldPattern[head_[arg__]] :> newHead[arg]
(* newHead[b[c, d]] *)
```

---

**My question is**: Is there any way to replace both `a` and `b` with `newHead` using a transformation rule?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll`

```
Replace[a[b[c, d]], head_[arg__] :> newHead[arg], {0, Infinity}]
```

> `newHead[newHead[c, d]]`

`ReplaceAll` fails to do what you want because it acts from the outside in. Once it found a match (the entire expression) on the outside, its job was done. `Replace` on the other hand, acts from inside out.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why `Replace` work but not `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: @seismatica see my update.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the reason `//.` would still not work is that each time the rule is repeated, it keeps on replacing the `newHead` again with `newHead`, without ever touching the `b`?

Comment: @seismatica It should touch the inside heads in that case. You could do that with `(head: Except[newHead])[arg__]` to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: Did you mean your method (using `Except`), and not mine (`a[b[c, d]] //. head_[arg__] :> newHead[arg]`) would touch the head? My use of `//.` did not work even though yours does (nice trick btw).

Comment: @seismatica Oh yes, sorry, that was not clear.

Comment: @RunnyKine do you have a reference for the `ReplaceAll` applying from the inside out? The closest thing I've found is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Blz.png), from [ref](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).

Comment: If that's the case than why would `h[x + h[u]] /. h :> k` work to replace all head `h` to `k`, even though one `h` is clearly within another `h`. I'm again confused O.o?

Comment: @seismatica. See [Leonid's book](http://mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node328.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me to that book. That section is very helpful! The book says that "this behavior is rather logical", but I just don't think it's very logical/intuitive at all. Why can't `ReplaceAll` work with `h[x_]` the same way that it works with stuff like simply `h` (or `Times` in the book)? In other words, why would `ReplaceAll` replace simple stuff in the latter (seemingly at all levels) but quit after the first replacement if `h[x]` is involved?

Comment: I find the last statement that "`Replace` [...] acts from the inside out" rather missleading. What about `Replace[a[b[c, d]], head_[arg__] :> newHead[arg]]`?

Comment: @seismatica Compare `a[b[c[d]]] /. x_ /; Print[x] -> x` and `Replace[a[b[c[d]]], x_ /; Print[x] -> x, {0, Infinity}]`. Notice the order, and how the second doesn't test heads like `a` and `b` alone. This is because `Replace` tries to transform the "entire expression", and with the levelspec we have told it to do this at each level. So it starts at the inner parts of the expr and keeps widening its selection as it looks for a match. `ReplaceAll` is only replacing parts, so it can just walk forward through the tree. It "quits" because it replaces the whole expr and doesn't test the new part

Comment: @seismatica. Thanks for the accept :)

Comment: @RunnyKine You're welcome! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

This question has essentially been asked many times before, perhaps most recently here:

- [Converting hierarchies of rules to associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55745/121)

I addressed it myself when I demonstrated the use of [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) and [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPoint.html) in place of `ReplaceRepeated` to get the standard traversal in:

- [ReplaceRepeated seemingly omits some rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38668/121)

As already explained by RunnyKine [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) traverse the expression in an unusual way within the context of *Mathematica*.  See my self-Q&A for some examples:

- [How to perform a depth-first preorder traversal of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121)

Further, as stated in the documentation:

> ReplaceAll looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part, or on any of its subparts.

Combined with the traversal order this means that inner expressions will never be replaced if they are part of a larger expression that matches a rule.

mfvonh comments that you could use:

```
a[b[c, d]] //. (head : Except[newHead])[arg__] :> newHead[arg]
```

> ```
> newHead[newHead[c, d]]
> ```

However this is inefficient as the entire expression is rescanned for each replacement.  I explored this issue in some detail here:

- [How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)

---

seismatica wrote:

> I think I now know (how) `ReplaceAll` scans an expression. I'm still confused about how it replaces its matches. For example `h[h[u, h], h] /. x : head_[arg__] /; Print[x] :> x` finds all heads `h`, yet `h[h[u, h], h] /. h[arg__] :> k[arg]` only replaces the outermost `h`. @mfvonh mentions in his comment that "ReplaceAll "quits" because it replaces the whole expr and doesn't test the new part". If that's the case, then why would `h[h[u, h], h] /. h :> k` even though when any `h` is replaced, the expressions would also change.

Each case you cite is different from the original.  In the first example you use a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) that never is `True`, therefore every part of the expression that matches the pattern (without the condition) is checked (and printed) as `ReplaceAll` searches in vain for a match.  Note how the behavior changes if we use a condition that is always `True`:

```
h[h[u, h], h] /. x : head_[arg__] /; (Print[x]; True) :> x
```

> h[h[u,h],h]

> ```
> h[h[u, h], h]
> ```

The second example highlights an important yet perhaps subtle difference: only entire expressions that are replaced are skipped for further matching and replacement.  An expression head is like any other part of an expression and it can be replaced independently, therefore you *can* use `/.` to replace all heads of a certain kind (or which match a certain pattern) but you must not include arguments along with them.

Consider these examples:

```
SeedRandom[0]
expr = RandomInteger[9, {3, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{{7, 0, 8}, {2, 1, 5}}, {{8, 0, 6}, {7, 2, 1}}, {{0, 6, 1}, {2, 8, 6}}}
> ```

```
expr /. {x__} :> h[x]
```

> ```
> h[{{7, 0, 8}, {2, 1, 5}}, {{8, 0, 6}, {7, 2, 1}}, {{0, 6, 1}, {2, 8, 6}}]
> ```

```
expr /. List -> h
```

> ```
> h[h[h[7, 0, 8], h[2, 1, 5]], h[h[8, 0, 6], h[7, 2, 1]], h[h[0, 6, 1], h[2, 8, 6]]]
> ```

This head replacement can be used, for example, to sort all lists:

```
expr /. List -> Composition[Sort, List]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 1, 6}, {2, 6, 8}}, {{0, 6, 8}, {1, 2, 7}}, {{0, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 5}}}
> ```

Comment: I really appreciate the links you provided in your answer. I think I now know `ReplaceAll` scans an expression. I'm still confused about how it replaces its matches. For example `h[h[u, h], h] /. x : head_[arg__] /; Print[x] :> x` finds all heads `h`, yet `h[h[u, h], h] /. h[arg__] :> k[arg]` only replaces the outermost `h`. @mfvonh mentions in his comment that "ReplaceAll "quits" because it replaces the whole expr and doesn't test the new part". If that's the case, then why would `h[h[u, h], h] /. h :> k` even though when any `h` is replaced, the expressions would also change.

Comment: @seismatica I'll address those questions in an addendum.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @seismatica Done.  It took longer than expected but I think it was worth it.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was my hunch as well (about no further replacement is made if the expression, and not just the head, is matched), but I just wish I could find somewhere in the documentation (or any MMA material for that matter) that mention this in more detail. The best I could find is [here](http://wolfram.com/xid/0fc8p25y3kmyjci-sao). I also appreciate your use of `Composition` as I've never seen it used before, though I wonder why something like `{3, 2, 1} /. List :> Sort[List[##]] &` would not also work (even though `Sort[List[##]] &[3, 2, 1]` does).

Comment: @seismatica Actually that does work, you just need to control grouping: `expr /. List :> (Sort[List[##]] &)`.  That is partly why I used `Composition`. :-)  By the way, in v10 we can write: `expr /. List -> Sort@*List`

Comment: perfect! Thank you so much. I really wish I could also accept your extensive answer but I have to go with @RunnyKine's since his directly answers my question, plus it's not like you're short on reps ;)

Comment: @seismatica The reps [slip through my fingers!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wntX-a3jSY) =:o