# Applying functions repeatedly on parts of complicated expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, functional-style

I am dealing with expressions like

$$ \textrm{expr}=5D_{4,1}\langle12\rangle\langle23\rangle\big(-\langle15\rangle^2\langle24\rangle\langle34\rangle + \langle14\rangle\langle15\rangle\langle24\rangle\langle35\rangle - \langle14\rangle\langle15\rangle\langle23\rangle\langle45\rangle - \langle12\rangle\langle15\rangle\langle34\rangle\langle45\rangle \big) + \\
5D_{4,2}\langle12\rangle\langle23\rangle\big(-\langle15\rangle\langle24\rangle\langle25\rangle\langle34\rangle + \langle14\rangle\langle25\rangle\langle24\rangle\langle35\rangle - \langle12\rangle\langle24\rangle\langle35\rangle\langle45\rangle - \langle12\rangle\langle23\rangle\langle45\rangle^2 \big) +
5\langle12\rangle\langle23\rangle\big[D_{4,3} \big(\textrm{similar stuff}\big)+D_{4,4} \big(\textrm{similar stuff}\big)+D_{4,5} \big(\textrm{similar stuff}\big)\big]$$

Here, $D_{ij}$ are simply matrix elements, whereas the brackets $\langle ab\rangle$ are special objects that basically obey antisymmetry and a special identity, which I implemented, calling it `schId` (it boils down to a substitution rule for expressions of the form $\langle ij \rangle\langle kl \rangle - \langle ik \rangle\langle jl \rangle$ or obvious variations).

Now, if I try something like `expr//Simplify//schId`, nothing happens. Basically, `Simplify` tends to destroy the nice "factorization" of the matrix elements $D_{ij}$, which I had obtained with `Collect[#,D[i_,j_]]&` and then `schId` doesn't see any of the combinations of brackets that it knows how to replace.
Nevertheless, I can obtain the desired simplifications if I copy-paste each of the parentheses multiplied by $D_{4,k}\langle12\rangle\langle23\rangle$ and act on them with `//Simplify//schId` (two or three (potentially even more) consecutive times).
I've seen that those parenthesis can be obtained as parts of `expr`, namely `expr[[i,5]]` for $i=1,\dots,5$.

- **How can I ask Mathematica to try to apply a sequence of functions on all the subparts of a complicated expression**?
- Moreover, **how can I ask it to do it as many times as it is necessary, in order for the result not to change anymore**?

I hope the question is not very trivial: I have searched on the forum as well as on the Help (for functions like `Map` or `Apply`), but I couldn't find any working strategy for my problem.

**Code update**:
I am working with a package which defines my brackets.
A reasonable definition for them can be given as follows:

```
 sb[h__] := Signature[{h}] 〈Sort[{h}] /. List -> Sequence〉
```

In the package, arguments of the brackets are automatically sorted at each step in the computation.
I don't know how to do that, so I just wrote a sorting function:

```
sortarg = # //. {〈l__〉 :> Signature[{l}] 〈Sort[{l}] /. List -> Sequence〉} &;
```

Here's the function that implements the identity among the brackets:

```
schId = # //. {〈a_,b_〉 〈c_,d_〉 - 〈a_,c_〉 〈b_,d_〉 :> 〈a,d〉 〈c,b〉, 〈a_,b_〉 〈c_,d_〉 + 〈a_,c_〉 〈d_,b_〉 :> 〈a,d〉 〈c,b〉, -〈a_,b_〉 〈c_,d_〉 - 〈a_,c_〉 〈d_,b_〉 :> -〈a,d〉 〈c,b〉, 〈a_,b_〉 〈c_,d_〉 - 〈a_,d_〉 〈c_,b_〉 :> 〈a,c〉 〈b,d〉, 〈a_,b_〉 〈c_,d_〉 + 〈a_,d_〉 〈b_,c_〉 :> 〈a,c〉 〈b,d〉, -〈a_,b_〉 〈c_,d_〉 - 〈a_,d_〉 〈b_,c_〉 :> -〈a,c〉 〈b,d〉} &;
```

(there must be a more elegant way to list all those substitution rules, but I cannot get even `PlusMinus` to work)

Easy example: `sb[2, 1] sb[3, 4] - sb[1, 4] sb[2, 3] // schId`
Real example (first summand of `expr`):

```
expr1 = 5 matD[4, 1] 〈1,2〉 〈2,3〉 (-〈1,5〉^2 〈2,4〉 〈3,4〉 + 〈1,4〉 〈1,5〉 〈2,4〉 〈3,5〉 - 〈1,4〉 〈1,5〉 〈2,3〉 〈4,5〉 - 〈1,2〉 〈1,5〉 〈3,4〉 〈4,5〉)
```

This gives zero when writing
`expr1 // Simplify // schId // sortarg // Simplify // schId // sortarg`

So my questions would be:

- How to ask Mathematica to act repeatedly on an `expr1` with `Simplify`, `schId`, `sortarg`?
- How to make it possible to use those functions directly on `expr` and not on its subparts?

Comment: Please provide your code, or a simplified version of it, including the definitions of your brackets.  Otherwise, it is very difficult for the reader to provide useful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a place to start I suggest [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html):

```
FullSimplify[expr1, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, schId, sortarg}]
```

> 0

This works even if both `sortarg` and `schId` are defined with `/.` rather than `//.`.

For more manual application consider [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html).  Also  familiarize yourself with [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121).

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Wizard, this is very helpful!
I'll wait just a bit more to accept the answer, in case somebody wants to share some further ideas.

Comment: @AndreaOrta I am glad it is helpful.  Please do not feel pressure to Accept this.  It is far from a complete and orderly answer.  I found the question a bit confusing in a quick read and I didn't want to take time to re-read it carefully.  Therefore I recommended one fairly general solution rather than providing a detailed answer.  I hope to return to this though honestly I'll probably find some other problem to distract me.  (continued)

Comment: @AndreaOrta One thing for now: understand the evaluation order difference between `Replace` or `MapAll` and `ReplaceAll`/`ReplaceRepeated`.  Some references:  [(9233)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233/121),
[(20181)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20181/121),
[(56062)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56062/121).