# Export dataset to JSON including Unicode Characters

Tags: export, data, dataset, json-format

I'm experiencing a weird issue. Consider a dataset defined like this:

```
dataset = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>}];
```

Now I would expect `Export["test.json", dataset]` to create a JSON file with these contents:

```
[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}].
```

Instead, the command returns

> Export::badval: The element Data contains invalid values. >>.

A workaround is to run

```
Export["test.json", Normal[Normal[dataset]]]
```

but that seems merely a workaround. Is there anyone here who knows a neat solution?

Comment: The JSON doc page says: Export["file.json", expr] exports a *list of rules* to JSON. Clearly, a Dataset is no such thing. Your "workaround" does the required conversion to this list of rules in a straightforward manner. I wouldn't call it a workaround, as there is no bug to work around.

Comment: `Export`, which is probably a mess of special cases internally, doesn't seem to have been given the full update treatment in V10.0.0. It dosesn't handle the new structured data objects gracefully. We are probably stuck with this for now. Hopefully, it will be fixed in V10.0.1, coming real soon now (this month, according to WRI tech support).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. I don't think the `Export` failure the OP is reporting is intentional. `Export` doesn't complain about being given a single association, which is not a list or rules.

Comment: Thanks. Fair enough, `Export` doesn't claim to be able to export datasets, but let's hope it does after the update. It seems a highly logical feature. For the time being, is there another way to convert a dataset to a JSON string without exporting it?

Comment: `ExportString` ?

Comment: This won't be fixed for 10.0.1, but it's a high-priority issue, and we'll try tackle it for 10.0.2.

Comment: I too would like to see easy Mathematica Export of Dataset objects to formats such as XML, JSON, CSV and others.  It will need to address the various kinds of data that can be wrapped in a Dataset. Yes, experts can use Normal and knowledge of Mathematica to fiddle and get a reasonable Export, but the "Automation Principal" suggests this should not be necessary.  I appreciate that it's a high-priority issue.

Comment: WRI focus too much on toy use cases in testing, eg currently useless SemanticImport: we have study filenames that start with Q - SemanticImport casts these values to an electrical unit, among other bizarre issues not worth fixing.

Comment: I think [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102692/rawjson-vs-json-format/102701) is relevant on the discussion here

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue.  `Dataset` and nested `Association`s have a structure ideally suited for JSON export, but the JSON exporter only supports lists of rules.  Any other type of expression triggers the error you see.

#### Export

The workaround is to recursively convert all nested associations to lists of rules.

```
normalAsc[expr_] := expr //. a_Association :> Normal[a]

normalAsc@Normal[dataset]

(* ==> {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}, {"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4}} *)
```

This can now be exported to JSON.

```
ExportString[normalAsc@Normal[dataset], "JSON"]
(* "[
    {
        \"a\": 1,
        \"b\": 2
    },
    {
        \"a\": 3,
        \"b\": 4
    }
]" *)
```

#### Import

After importing JSON, we also need a way to convert it back to a nested association, then a `Dataset`.  This can be done as follows:

```
Dataset@Replace[json, {r__Rule} :> Association[r], {0, Infinity}]
```

The key here is to use `Replace`, which scans the expression from the inside to outside.  `ReplaceAll` would go from the outside to the inside, and once a list of rules has been changed to an `Association`, it won't be possible to replace inside it any more.

**Update:** Looks like there's a simpler way, [`ToAssociation` (undocumented)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55745/converting-hierarchies-of-rules-to-associations/55746#55746).

---

A while ago I sent a suggestion to WRI support about allowing nested associations and possibly `Dataset` to be exported to JSON.  The more people suggest a feature, the more likely that it'll get implemented.   You can consider suggesting it too.

Comment: Thanks, Szabolcs. This is at least a proper workaround. How should we go about making a feature request to WRI?

Comment: @Thijs I think either [here](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) or usual email to support at wolfram.com.  I wouldn't expect much unless several people ask for the same though. (At least two of us for now.)

Comment: btw, the undocumented [`ToAssociation`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55746/5) can also be used to convert imported json to associations.

Answer (score 3):

Using *Mathematica* v10.3

```
dataset = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>}];

Export["test.json", dataset]
```

works without any errors and results in a file with the following, expected structure:

```
[
    {"a": 1, "b": 2},
    {"a": 3, "b": 4}
]
```

To get the `Dataset` back from this file one can use

```
dataset = Dataset@Import["test.json", "RawJSON"]
```

Comment: It is not working with Unicode, see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica 10.3 the answer above is not working with Unicode characters

```
dataset=Dataset[{<|"a"->1,"b"->2,"\[CapitalLambda]"->3|>,<|"a"->3,"b"->4,"\[CapitalLambda]"->5|>}]

Export["test.json", dataset]
```

File content is

```
[
     {"a": 1, "b": 2, "\[CapitalLambda]": 3},
     {"a": 3, "b": 4, "\[CapitalLambda]": 5}
]
```

But if you try now

```
dataset = Dataset@Import["test.json", "RawJSON"]

Import::jsoninvescchar: Unexpected escaped character '[' >>
Import::jsonkvsep: "Missing key value separator ':'.
Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character 'C', at line 2:23 >>
Dataset`ExtractRawData::dataextr: Data extraction failed.
Dataset[$Failed]
```

The trick is to export first in "RawJSON" then import the "RawJSON" but Export does not seem to have any option for Unicode. That is why I used ExportString

```
In:  jstr=ExportString[Normal@dataset, "RawJSON", "Compact"->True]
Out: [{"a":1,"b":2,"\[CapitalLambda]":3},{"a":3,"b":4,"\[CapitalLambda]":5}]

Export["test.txt",jstr]
```

Now you can get the dataset with

```
dataset=Dataset@Import["test.txt","RawJSON"]
```

Comment: I think [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102692/rawjson-vs-json-format/102701) is relevant on the discussion here

Comment: Please notice that [CapitalLamba] character is Greek lambda (Λ), Unicode: 039B, and the whole point of any similar test like the one above is that after importing a dataset with Unicode strings you should get a Notebook output formatted with your Language encoding, NOT with full names, e.g. [CapitalLambda]