# Turns nested Lists into nested Associations, ReplaceAll for list vs ReplacsAll for association

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I want to transform some nested lists into nested associations except the `"rows"->List` pattern.

Here is the example

```
s={"sensor" -> {"opto" -> {"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_opto.csv", 
     "data" -> {"time" -> {"unit" -> "s", "rows" -> {1}}, 
       "4" -> {"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {2, 3}}, 
       "1" -> {"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {4, 5}}}}, 
   "qmb1" -> {"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_qmb1.csv", 
     "data" -> {"qmb1" -> {"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {2}}, 
       "time" -> {"unit" -> "s", "rows" -> {1}}}}, 
   "saw" -> {"filename" -> "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_saw.csv",
      "data" -> {"time" -> {"unit" -> "s", "rows" -> {1}}, 
       "15" -> {"unit" -> "Hz", "rows" -> {5, 6}}, 
       "10" -> {"unit" -> "Hz", "rows" -> {2, 3, 4}}, 
       "9" -> {"unit" -> "Hz", "rows" -> {7, 8, 9}}}}, 
   "qmb2" -> {"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_qmb2.csv", 
     "data" -> {"time" -> {"unit" -> "s", "rows" -> {1}}, 
       "qmb2" -> {"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {2}}, 
       "flow" -> {"unit" -> "sscm", "rows" -> {4}}, 
       "temperature" -> {"unit" -> "\[Degree]C", "rows" -> {3}}, 
       "humidity" -> {"unit" -> "%", "rows" -> {5}}}}}, 
 "date" -> {"year" -> 2016, "month" -> 11, "sec" -> 10, "day" -> 17, 
   "hour" -> 14, "min" -> 18}, "serie" -> 1, 
 "compound" -> "multi-detection", "inLab" -> 0, "proto" -> 1, 
 "uuid" -> "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554"}
```

So far I have done:

```
ReplaceAll[s, List :> Association]
```

which gives

```
<|"sensor" -> <|"opto" -> <|"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_opto.csv", 
     "data" -> <|"time" -> <|"unit" -> "s", 
         "rows" -> Association[1]|>, 
       "4" -> <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[2, 3]|>, 
       "1" -> <|"unit" -> "intensity", 
         "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>|>|>, 
   "qmb1" -> <|"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_qmb1.csv", 
     "data" -> <|"qmb1" -> <|"unit" -> "intensity", 
         "rows" -> Association[2]|>, 
       "time" -> <|"unit" -> "s", "rows" -> Association[1]|>|>|>, 
   "saw" -> <|"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_saw.csv", 
     "data" -> <|"time" -> <|"unit" -> "s", 
         "rows" -> Association[1]|>, 
       "15" -> <|"unit" -> "Hz", "rows" -> Association[5, 6]|>, 
       "10" -> <|"unit" -> "Hz", "rows" -> Association[2, 3, 4]|>, 
       "9" -> <|"unit" -> "Hz", "rows" -> Association[7, 8, 9]|>|>|>, 
   "qmb2" -> <|"filename" -> 
      "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554_qmb2.csv", 
     "data" -> <|"time" -> <|"unit" -> "s", 
         "rows" -> Association[1]|>, 
       "qmb2" -> <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[2]|>, 
       "flow" -> <|"unit" -> "sscm", "rows" -> Association[4]|>, 
       "temperature" -> <|"unit" -> "\[Degree]C", 
         "rows" -> Association[3]|>, 
       "humidity" -> <|"unit" -> "%", 
         "rows" -> Association[5]|>|>|>|>, 
 "date" -> <|"year" -> 2016, "month" -> 11, "sec" -> 10, "day" -> 17, 
   "hour" -> 14, "min" -> 18|>, "serie" -> 1, 
 "compound" -> "multi-detection", "inLab" -> 0, "proto" -> 1, 
 "uuid" -> "137fb39d9a39f0e18ec49f4a68d72554"|>
```

However I am stuck here, because `ReplaceAll` does not seem to work for `Association` as it works for `List`. By example:

```
ReplaceAll[Normal@<|"unit" -> "intensity","rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>, 
           ("rows" -> a_Association) :> ("rows" -> Apply[List, a])]
```

gives (as expected)

```
{"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {4, 5}}
```

but

```
ReplaceAll[<|"unit" -> "intensity","rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>, 
           ("rows" -> a_Association) :> ("rows" -> Apply[List, a])]
```

has no effect

```
<|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>
```

**Questions**

- why `ReplaceAll` does not work for `Association`?
- how to turns `"rows"->Association[4,5,...]` into `"rows"->{4,5,...}` in my association (`"rows"->...` can be at any place)

**Note:** I am using MMA v10

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `ToAssociations` from the ```"GeneralUtilities`"``` package, for which you can find examples in the answers to other questions. Associations were new with 10.0 and replacing within associations was not working from the beginning, so it would be necessary to know which exact version you are using if you are seeking for alternatives to `ToAssociations`...

Comment: I think [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55745/169) might be a duplicate...

Comment: @AlbertRetey you are right, thanks to pointing this out

Comment: @AlbertRetey the version I am using right now is v10.0, I am also interested by solution working under MMA v11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* This answers the question of how to achieve the specific replacement in the question and why the original attempt does not work. To do the actual conversion, it is better to use `` GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations ``, as mentioned [in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198166/turns-nested-lists-into-nested-associations-replaceall-for-list-vs-replacsall-f/198168#comment513287_198166), and [the question linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55745/169) there.

The problem is that keys of associations are invisible to most functions, similar to how you don't see indices in normal lists (you can think of the keys as named indices). To see this, consider:

```
<|"a" -> "a", "b" -> {"a", "b"}|> /. "a" -> "xx"
(* <|"a" -> "xx", "b" -> {"xx", "b"}|> *)
```

As you can see, the keys are not touched.

There are several ways to work around this:

- Use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) to transform the given entry. This will not work in all cases, but it is very clear in its intent.

  ```
  MapAt[Apply[List], "rows"]@<|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>
  (* <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {4, 5}|> *)
  ```

  You can also use [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) to the same effect:

  ```
  Query[{"rows" -> Apply[List]}]@<|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>
  (* <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {4, 5}|> *)
  ```
- Use the second syntax of [`AssociationMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationMap.html). This only works for the top-level association in its current form, but is otherwise very close in functionality:

  ```
  AssociationMap[
   Replace[("rows" -> a_Association) :> ("rows" -> Apply[List, a])],
   <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>
   ]

  <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> {4, 5}|>
  ```
- Match the whole association. This is pretty close to your original attempt, but has the disadvantage that the association can only be matched once, and it a bit harder to read. (this appears to only work starting with 11.0 or so)

  ```
  ReplaceAll[
   <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|>,
   <|pre___, "rows" -> a_Association, post___|> :>
    <|pre, "rows" -> Apply[List, a], post|>
   ]
  (* <|"unit" -> "intensity", "rows" -> Association[4, 5]|> *)
  ```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you have an idea how to do this without any assumptions? I mean  remplacing "rows"->Association[...] by "rows"->List{...} without any further assumptions?

Comment: Which assumptions do you mean exactly?

Comment: not using the fact that "rows" key is a member of `<|"unit"->... etc... |>`. Said another way a solution that works for my whole example, not only for the  `<|"unit"->... etc... |>` part

Comment: As mentioned in the note I've added to the top of the answer, I'd suggest you use ``GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations`` for your problem (in all versions of Mathematica). The answer is more intended as a "Why does this not work and how to fix it" than as a "How to do it best"

Comment: ops, sorry. I will test that, thanks