# difficulty abstracting the OptionValue pattern

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, options, associations

I am building lots of functions that use `Options` and `OptionValue` and wanted to reduce the redundancy in the expressions that define the functions. I will show a tiny example, here, but please imagine that instead of a couple of options with names like `a` and `b`, my real examples have dozens of options with names like

```
blancmangeWithRaisinsAndPartiallyHydrogenatedChocolateSauce
```

and you will easily understand why I want to do what I want to do.

What do I want to do? My functions fit the following pattern:

The following defines the acceptable optional parameters for `foo`: they are `a` and `b`, and they have default values 1 and 2, respectively. The acceptable options are defined separately from the body of the function. A caller may supply values for `a` or `b` or both or neither, using option syntax below.

```
ClearAll[foo];
Options[foo] = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2};
```

The following defines the body of the function. This function produces an association object with attributes corresponding to the values of the optional parameters.

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] :=
  <|"a" -> OptionValue["a"],
   "b" -> OptionValue["b"]|>;
```

The following is a call that supplies only the optional value for a.

```
foo["a" -> 42]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 42, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

The following is a call that supplies both a and b; notice that the order does not matter.

```
foo["b" -> 43, "a" -> 42]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 42, "b" -> 43|>
> ```

The following is a call that supplies neither a nor b.

```
foo[]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

I want to reduce the redundancy in the definition expression for `foo`. I define a helper:

```
ClearAll[opt];
opt[nym_] := Rule[nym, OptionValue[nym]];
```

Hoping for a new style of definition for `foo`:

```
foo[OptionsPattern[]] = <|opt["a"], opt["b"]|>
```

Notice that I used `Set` and not `SetDelayed` because I wanted the right-hand side to be evaluated at definition time, not at call time.  But still no dice: `foo` doesn't work any more

```
foo[]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> OptionValue["a"], "b" -> OptionValue["b"]|>
> ```

Its options are still in-force

```
Options[foo]
```

> ```
> {a -> 1, b -> 2}
> ```

Why doesn't my little trick work?  Why doesn't `opt` rewrite in the context of the definiing expression for `foo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is probably related to the way OptionValue[name] is evaluated. When you use a regular List instead of an Association, you'll find the whole thing works. I don't have the mathematica-fu to understand why in detail, but here is an alternative solution that makes your function definitions pretty concise.

Define a utility function that reads options for a symbol, converts to an association, and merges in another set of options as an association:

```
getem[sym_, opts_: {}] := Association[Association[Options[sym]], Association[opts]];
```

You first of all set your options for your symbol:

```
Options[bob] = { "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4 };
```

Now your function definitions are pretty terse:

```
bob[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := getem[bob, opts];
```

And it evaluates the way you want:

```
bob[]
```

> <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>

```
bob["d" -> 59]
```

> <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 59|>

As another exercise you could probably meta-program your way into generating the bob[] style functions, but I have not plumbed the depths of mathematica there as yet :) I'm confident it's possible based on some of the crazy stuff I've seen so far.

Comment: Clever merging of Associations and works well.

Comment: This is a better answer because I only need to mention each option string once: minimal opportunity for typos.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this results from `Association` being [atomic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55529/121) (or "not NormalQ" as Taliesin puts it) without being fully overloaded to behave as a normal expression of equivalent structure.  Observe:

```
asc = <|"a" -> q, "b" -> r, "c" -> s|>;
Block[{q = 1, r = 2, s = 3}, asc]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> q, "b" -> r, "c" -> s|>
> ```

Also:

```
With[{q = 1, r = 2, s = 3}, Evaluate @ asc]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> q, "b" -> r, "c" -> s|>
> ```

One might expect that because the association is constructed from `Rule` rather than `RuleDelayed` the Values (right-hand-sides) would evaluate inside the `Block` but they do not.  Further, one might think that the seemingly literal appearance of `q`, `r`, and `s` in the `Association` would allow them to be replaced using `With` but again it does not.  In these ways `Association` objects diverge from the normal evaluation rules.

Your original definition works because the right-hand-side is not an actual `Association` object: it is merely input syntax for one.  Therefore the `OptionValue["a"]` etc. are both substituted and evaluated *before* the `Association` is constructed.

To make your pattern work we merely need to inject the body of the association while allowing the `<| |>` syntax to remain held via `SetDelayed`:

```
Options[foo] = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2};

opt[nym_] := Rule[nym, OptionValue[nym]];

(foo[OptionsPattern[]] := <|##|>) &[opt["a"], opt["b"]]
```

Test:

```
foo["a" -> 7]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 7, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

Comment: `With[{opts = Sequence[opt["a"], opt["b"]]}, 
 foo[OptionsPattern[]] := <|opts|>]` also seems to work.

Comment: @seismatica I guess it would, but `## &` is shorter. :-)

Comment: An important (if very oblique) clue is in the documentation for `Association`: "Normal converts an Association to a list of rules."  That implies that `Association` isn't normal, lest `Normal` do anything at all to it.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Unfortunately that doesn't really tell us much since `Normal` works on a number of standard expressions as well. (e.g. `GraphicsComplex`.)  Further, even if `Association` is atomic it could still behave more like a standard expression; `SparseArray` is also atomic yet you will find that the examples using `Block` and `With` *do* affect its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer because it's too long for a comment and it's a significant correction and amplification of @Hagus's answer.

First, we need for `options` to be a `BlankNullSequence` to handle natural call forms where options need not be packaged in lists:

```
ClearAll[constructorWithOptions];
constructorWithOptions[symbol_, options___Rule] :=
  <|<|Options[symbol]|>, <|options|>|>

ClearAll[foo];
Options[foo] = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2};
foo[options : OptionsPattern[]] := constructorWithOptions[foo, options];
foo[]
foo["a" -> 41]
foo["b" -> 42]
foo["b" -> 42, "a" -> 41]
foo["c" -> 43]
foo["a" -> 41, "c" -> 43]
foo["b" -> 42, "c" -> 43]
foo["b" -> 42, "c" -> 43, "a" -> 41]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 2|>
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 42|>
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 42|>
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 43|>
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 43|>
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 42, "c" -> 43|>
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 42, "c" -> 43|>
> ```

This construct admits options that are *not* defined for `foo`. This may be acceptable if we're allowing mixins, but if we want the more familiar behavior of rejecting unknown options, we can do something like this:

```
ClearAll[constructorWithOnlyOptions];
constructorWithOnlyOptions[symbol_, options___Rule] := (
  symbol::nodef = "unknown option `1` for " <> ToString[symbol];
  With[{
      acceptableNames = First /@ Options[symbol],
      proposedNames = First /@ {options}},
    With[{
        acceptedProposals = Intersection[acceptableNames, proposedNames],
        rejectedProposals = Complement[proposedNames, acceptableNames]},
      Message[symbol::nodef, #] & /@ rejectedProposals;
      <|<|Options[symbol]|>, <|
        Select[{options}, MemberQ[acceptedProposals, First[#]]& ]|>|> ] ]);

ClearAll[foo];
Options[foo] = {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2};
foo[options : OptionsPattern[]] := constructorWithOnlyOptions[foo, options];
foo[]
foo["a" -> 41]
foo["b" -> 42]
foo["b" -> 42, "a" -> 41]
foo["c" -> 43]
foo["a" -> 41, "c" -> 43]
foo["b" -> 42, "c" -> 43]
foo["b" -> 42, "c" -> 43, "a" -> 41]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 2|>
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 42|>
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 42|>
> foo::nodef: unknown option c for foo
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
> foo::nodef: unknown option c for foo
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 2|>
> foo::nodef: unknown option c for foo
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 42|>
> foo::nodef: unknown option c for foo
> <|"a" -> 41, "b" -> 42|>
> ```

This isn't perfect, because it associates the `Message` with `foo` instead of with `OptionValue`, but I think it's good enough for production use.

Now, encapsulate the options:

```
ClearAll[defineConstructor];
defineConstructor[symbol_] :=
  ( symbol[options:OptionsPattern[]] :=
    constructorWithOnlyOptions[symbol, options] );

ClearAll[foo];
Options[foo] = {"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4};
defineConstructor[foo];
foo[]
foo["c" -> 43]
foo["d" -> 44]
foo["d" -> 44, "c" -> 43]
foo["e" -> 45]
foo["e" -> 46, "d" -> 44, "f" -> 46]
```

> ```
> <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> <|"c" -> 43, "d" -> 4|>
> <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 44|>
> <|"c" -> 43, "d" -> 44|>
> foo::nodef: unknown option e for foo
> <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>
> foo::nodef: unknown option e for foo
> foo::nodef: unknown option f for foo
> <|"c" -> 3, "d" -> 44|>
> ```

```
Options[foo]
```

> ```
> {"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}
> ```