# Pattern match for nested Association

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

Suppose I have `Association`

```
testAssoc=Association[a->Association[1->1,2->2],b->Association[1->1,2->2]]
```

which pattern match this `Association`?

PS: of course `MatchQ[testAssoc, _Association]`  return true, but I want to match ONLY nested `Associations`

Comment: An Association is an atom in Mathematica, so formally it has no deeper structure. It is not even an expression with head Association and some arguments; the command MatchQ[testAssoc, Association[___]] returns False. So I think the best you can do is first to use functions like  Normal or Values: MatchQ[Values[testAssoc], {__Association}]] returns True.

Comment: In 10.4 you can match within Associations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently pattern - matcher doesn' t go inside an `Association`, and `_Association` is an exception (head test). You can note, for example, that an `Association` is `AtomQ` (although this is only a consequence of that). So, if you want to use pure patterns, you're *currently* out of luck. But, you can use recursive patterns. In this case:

```
nestedAssocPattern = assoc_Association /; MemberQ[Values[assoc], _Association]
```

Now, you can test:

```
MatchQ[testAssoc, nestedAssocPattern]

(* True *)

MatchQ[<|1 -> 2|>, nestedAssocPattern]

(* False *)
```

Comment: The pattern should be `assoc_Association /; MatchQ[Values[assoc], {__Association}]`, I believe; the current form will match `<|1 -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 4|>, 2 -> 5|>`, which I believe is not wanted.

Comment: @J.M. You may be right, but the question does not give enough information to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

With 10.4 you can use `KeyValuePattern`, or you can do it directly with a condition.

This gives elements whose keys are Associations:

```
Cases[{<|a -> <|1 -> 1|>, b -> <|2 -> 2|>|>, <|a -> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>, c -> 4|>}, 
    x_Association /; Union[Head /@ Values@x] == {Association}, {1}]

(* {<|a -> <|1 -> 1|>, b -> <|2 -> 2|>|>}  *)
```

Comment: It will also match `<|b -> <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>, c -> 1|>` which is not nested association in this context.

Comment: So he wants a pattern that matches associations where all keys are associations, right?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not 100% sure :-/

Comment: @M.R., beware that KeyValuePattern only matches the first matching Key-Value rules in an Association and will not match subsequent ones. That behavior is at odds with replacement in Lists, eg if the Association is Normalized to a List.

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out by others `Association` objects are presently not traversed by pattern matching.

See:

- [MatchQ-ing Associations (MMA 10)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55526/121)
- [difficulty abstracting the OptionValue pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58103/121)

My interpretation of your question is that you want to test to see if *all* values in the top Association are themselves Associations, rather than testing if only *one* value is, which is what kguler and Leonid answered.  Therefore I propose:

```
asc_Association /; MatchQ[Values[asc], {__Association}]
```

This checks that entire expression and all of its values are Associations.

---

One could almost use this Condition instead of `MatchQ`: `AllTrue[asc, AssociationQ]` except that:

```
AllTrue[<||>, AssociationQ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
foo=!FreeQ[#,_Association,1]&;

testAssoc=Association[a->Association[1->1,2->2],b->Association[1->1,2->2]];
testAssoc2=Association[a->aa,b->bb];
testAssoc3=List[a->Association[1->1,2->2],b->Association[1->1,2->2]];

foo/@{testAssoc,testAssoc2,testAssoc3}
(* {True, False, False} *)
```