# A bug in the overloading of MemberQ and FreeQ for Association?

Tags: bugs, core-language, associations, expression-test

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1.0.**

---

While answering [Pattern match for nested Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61574/121) I came across behavior of [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html) and [`FreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FreeQ.html) in 10.0.1 that I believe is incorrect.  The option `Heads -> False` does not work properly:

```
expr1 = foo[bar, baz];
expr2 = <|1 -> a, 2 -> b|>;

MemberQ[expr1, _?Print, Heads -> False];
```

> bar
>
> baz

```
MemberQ[expr2, _?Print, Heads -> False];
```

> Association
>
> a
>
> b

```
FreeQ[expr1, _?Print, Heads -> False];
```

> bar
>
> baz
>
> foo[bar,baz]

```
FreeQ[expr2, _?Print, Heads -> False];
```

> Association
>
> a
>
> b
>
> <|1->a,2->b|>

Observe that in both cases `Association` is checked against the pattern even though `foo` is not.

---

Sjoerd wrote:

> I believe the error is not the printing of `Association` but that it prints anything at all. `Association` is atomic and it should have no (visible) members. Compare with `expr3=Graph[{1->2}]`.

The 10.0.1 documentation says:

> `MemberQ` works on associations, testing values but not keys.
>
> `FreeQ` works on associations, testing values but not keys.

Therefore this overloading is documented and I believe options should work propertly.

Comment: I believe the error is not the printing of `Association` but that it prints anything at all. `Association` is atomic and it should have no (visible) members. Compare with `expr3=Graph[{1->2}]`.

Comment: @Sjoerd Please see update.

Comment: **I see that this Question has six votes.  Shall I read that to mean that people agree that this appears to be a bug, and tag it as such?**

Comment: AFAIC yes, and you were right with your update concerning the documentation. I hadn't seen the updates to these parts of the documenation.

Comment: Reported and confirmed as a bug.

Comment: In v 10.0.2, now I get this: I do not know if this is the correct output you expect or not, but here it is: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gHW3z.png)

Comment: @Nasser you used `expr1` instead of `expr2` which is needed to illustrate the problem.  In 10.0.2 using `Heads -> False` in either `MemberQ` or `FreeQ` still causes `Association` to be checked against the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Lichtblau confirmed that this was a bug.  It has been corrected in version 10.1.0.