# Non sequitur in documentation of MemberQ

Tags: core-language, documentation

Mr.Wizard's [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61619/3066) about `MemberQ` and `FreeQ` got me to re-read the documentation for those functions. I find I don't understand the 3rd bullet point made under **Details and Options** of [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html).

> `MemberQ[list, form]` immediately tests whether any expression in `list` matches `form`; `Element[x, dom]` asserts that `x` is an element of the symbolic domain `dom`.

Can someone explain what point is being made here? The text after the semicolon reads as a *non sequitur* to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this wording was introduced in the [V4 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/MemberQ.html).  It predates the current documentation conventions where relationships and contrasts between functions are usually noted under the *Properties & Relations* heading.  So I think that the wording is simply there to guide the user to the `Element` function if the goal is to do domain-testing instead of testing list membership.

The two concepts are very similar if not identical in mathematical writing: "*i* being a member of the set of integers", "*i* being an element of  *{1, 2, 3, 4}*".  *Mathematica* artificially distinguishes the operations for practical reasons, and the documentation is pointing this out.

Comment: That historical explanation of why they put the wording in the front section seems to make sense (+1).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this statement looks almost as if the last part is just a repetition of the first part with different wording, but for a different command. But there is an important difference, ad the juxtaposition of the two commands `MemberQ` and `Element` is probably intended to highlight that difference:

It's all in the word **immediate**. The difference is probably best illustrated by example:

```
Element[f[x], Reals]

(* ==> f[x] ∈ Reals *)

MemberQ[{1, 2}, f[x]]

(* ==> False *)
```

In the case of `Element`, the expression remained **unevaluated** because `f[x]` wasn't defined so we can't decide whether it's real. *However*, `MemberQ` is not that patient. It gives `False` because at that `immediate` instant of evaluation, `f[x]` is explicitly of `Head` `f` and therefore doesn't explicitly belong to the list given.

So my interpretation is that the statement in the documentation is intended to point out this distinction between `MemberQ` and `Element`.

Comment: You may be right, but I'm not convinced. To me there is no context in this sentence to establish any relation at all between `MemberQ` and `Element`. And, since the sentence stands alone, no other context to establish a relationship, either.

Comment: I'm going by my knowledge of what all the other functions ending in `Q` also do. They differ from tests such as `Element` in that they assign a truth value based on the immediate, explicit structure of the argument. Think of `TrueQ`: it's very quick to give `False` because it only gives you `True` if you give it `True` first. In other words, functions ending in `Q` don't ever give "maybe" as an answer...