# Association matching still not working perfectly?

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, associations, assignment, rule

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and persisting through 11.1.1**

---

Up until 10.4 you could not match on internal `Association` structure at all: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119542/6804

Now you can, but it seems flawed still: the following patterns should match `<|"c" -> {0}|>` but not `<|"c" -> {1}|>`. These work:

```
gok1[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_List /; First@c == 0}] := 0;
gok2[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_List}] := 0 /; First@c == 0;
```

(I still don't understand why they support the second variant, after all the RHS in := should not be a Pattern...).

But this one does not:

```
gfail[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_List}] /; First@c == 0 := 0;
```

giving `First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[c].` **but only the first time it is used**, e.g. via

```
gfail[<|"c" -> {0}|>]
gfail[<|"c" -> {1}|>]
```

or

```
gfail[{"c" -> {0}}]
gfail[{"c" -> {1}}]
```

So the culprit seems to be the `KeyValuePattern`.
If it is not involved, everything works fine:

```
hok[{"c" -> c_List}] /; First@c == 0 := 0;
hok1[{"c" -> c_List /; First@c == 0}] := 0;
hok2[{"c" -> c_List}] := 0 /; First@c == 0;

hok[{"c" -> {0}}]
hok[{"c" -> {1}}]
hok1[{"c" -> {0}}]
hok1[{"c" -> {1}}]
hok2[{"c" -> {0}}]
hok2[{"c" -> {1}}]
```

Am I missing something or can somebody confirm this as a probable bug?

Comment: It seems in `patt /; test` `c` isn't shared but for `lhs:>rhs/;test` it is: `a : KeyValuePattern[{"c" -> c_List}] :> a /; (First[c] === 0)`. Just an observation, don't know if the observerd behavior is to be expected (isn't for me).

Comment: Is it useful to make contact with these answers? ([108925](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108925/1806)) ([109383](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109383/1806))

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug that the local variable `c` isn't shared with `Condition` when the latter appears at the LHS outside of the `KeyValuePattern`. The following simplified examples demonstrate the bug:

```
gfail1[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_}] /; c == 0 := 0
gfail2[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_} /; c == 0] := 0

gfail1[<|"c" -> 0|>]
gfail2[<|"c" -> 0|>]
```

> ```
> gfail1[<|"c" -> 0|>]
>
> gfail2[<|"c" -> 0|>]
> ```

These cases demonstrate the expected behavior:

```
gok1[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_ /; c == 0}] := 0
gok2[KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_}] := 0 /; c == 0

gok1[<|"c" -> 0|>]
gok2[<|"c" -> 0|>]
```

> ```
> 0
>
> 0
> ```

Please report it to the tech support.

---

> (I still don't understand why they support the second variant, after all the RHS in := should not be a Pattern...).

Actually the RHS with `Condition` IS a part of the pattern expression, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869885/590388) excellent answer by Leonid Shifrin.

Comment: Alright, I filed a report.

Comment: @masterxilo Have you received any response?

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
test[p : KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_List}] /; First[p["c"]] == 0 := $Succeeded
test[p : KeyValuePattern@{"c" -> c_List}] := $Failed
```

then

```
test[<|"c" -> {0, 1}|>]
```

> `$Succeeded`

```
test[<|"c" -> {1, 1}|>]
```

> `$Failed`

Perhaps that is form you are looking for.

Comment: Nice, I didnt even try to find a workaround.